# what tools are used to run automation testing on office desktop apps (or any Desktop apps)

Tags: automated-testing, desktop-application

I am looking to run some test scripts on Desktop applications (such as office apps, webex, teams, etc.) to test for functionality after Monthly windows patches.

Does anyone have experience with testing Monthly patch updates, or automation testing desktop applications?

Are there any good tools out there (similar to selenium)?

or

just in general, any suggestions on how to tackle this one?

Comment: TestComplete can be used for automated desktop apps.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions for desktop app testing I encounter the more often are:

- [Leapwork](https://www.leapwork.com/technology/desktop-ui-automation)
- [Ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/windows-desktop-test-automation/)
- [TestComplete](https://smartbear.com/product/testcomplete/desktop-testing/)

[Quality Center](https://software.microfocus.com/en-us/products/quality-center-quality-management/overview) used to be the leader in this area but it seems he is lagging behind nowadays.

I don't have much experience with those tools though. As much as I can, I try to automate bellow the UI... and perform some manual testing on the UI layer when needed.

Comment: Got it, Thank you my friend, I will look into those tools, like i said, any info is appreciated.